# How to include class?

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

```
handlers/
     handler.php
src/
     Model.php
```

I'm trying include class
Model.php

```php
<?php 
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App;

class Model{
    }
```

handler.php

```php
<?php 
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/src/Model.php');

$model=new Model();
```

I get an error:

> Class 'Model' not found

Is it because I am using composer autoloader?

```json
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": ["src/"]


        }
    },
```

Comment: Try `__DIR__ . '/../src/Model.php'`

Comment: If you're using the composer autoloader, you don't need to include the model class in handler.php. You just need to include the composer autoload script. This is usually done at the entry point for your app. You will also need to either add a use statement for `App\Model` in handler.php, or use the fully qualified name of that class when you instantiate it there.

Comment: Where did you define that class `Model` (without any namespace)? As far as I see, you are using a class in the namespace `App`, which you should use as `new App\Model()` or through a `use`  statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model.php

```
<?php 

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace src;

class Model{}
```

Handler.php

```
<?php 
    
use src\Model;

require __DIR__ . '../vendor/autoload.php'; // or whatever to route is to your autoload file

$model=new Model();
```

The final thing I want to mention is that the directory specified in the autoload file should be a folder that contains all of your classes ideally. Beyond that, the namespaces should be subdirectories in the directory where that class can be located. So say you have the folder `Classes`, and then `src` may be under it, you would do:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "Classes/"
    }
},

namespace src;
```

This works if your class is in the `src` folder. If you added a subfolder of `src` with your class in it:

```
namespace src\subfolder;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. For example, why did you modify the namespace? How should your `Handler.php` find the class without any autoloader included?

Answer (score 0):

ok i'm found a solution. You need to connect autoload.php

```
<?php 
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
use App\Model;
$s=new Model();
```